# Recursion Problem in PHP

Tags: php, xml, recursion

I need to create a valid xml from a given array();

My Method looks like this,

```
protected function array2Xml($array)
    {
        $xml = "";

        if(is_array($array))
        {
            foreach($array as $key=>$value)
            {
                $xml .= "<$key>";

                if(is_array($value))
                {
                    $xml .= $this->array2Xml($value);
                }
                $xml .= "</$key>";
            }

            return $xml;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("in valid");
        }
    }


protected function createValidXMLfromArray($array,$node)
    {
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';

        $xmlArray = $this->array2Xml($array);

        $xml .= "<$node>$xmlArray</$node>";
        return $xml;
    }
```

if i execute the above i just get keys with empty values;

like

```
<node>
<name></name>
</node>
```

What i need is if i pass this `array("name"=>"test","value"=>array("test1"=>33,"test2"=>40));`

that it return this

```
<node>
<name>test</name>
<value>
<test1>33</test1>
<test2>40</test2>
</value>
</node>
```

Where is the error what did i wrong in the above recursion?

Comment: Just a note: I recommend creating XML using the DOM Classes http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Check out my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207599/multidimensional-array-iteration/2207739#2207739

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never placed the values into the code; your recursion is OK, you just missed the all-important step of supplying the data.  Try this on for size:

```
protected function array2Xml($array)
    {
        $xml = "";

        if(is_array($array))
        {
            foreach($array as $key=>$value)
            {
                $xml .= "<$key>";

                if(is_array($value))
                {
                    $xml .= $this->array2Xml($value);
                }
                else {
                    $xml .= $value;
                }
                $xml .= "</$key>\n";
            }

            return $xml;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("in valid");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the "else":

```
 if(is_array($value)) {
      $xml .= $this->array2Xml($value);
 } else {
      $xml .= $value;
 }
```

Comment: I dont know why but i get epty nodes

Comment: @streetparade: how is this any different to dereleased's answer which worked?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
if(is_array($value))
{
 $xml .= $this->array2Xml($value);
}
else
{
 $xml .= $value;
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing one thing, after your check if $value is array you need to add else
else $xml .= $value;

if you know what I mean