# Generating XML from PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to generate XML structures on the fly using PHP.
I've seen many different ways and libraries, but I would like to know which is the most efficient.

In general, I have arrays and its content has to be returned as an XML structure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimensional array iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207599/multidimensional-array-iteration/2207739#2207739) - the iterator approach can easily be adjusted to use DOM or another XML lib if you need to transform this into a DOM Tree instead of just outputting the XML.

Comment: efficient for the machine or the programmer?

Comment: there is no general *most efficient*. It depends on what you want to do with the XML. Also see http://devzone.zend.com/article/2387 for an overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most cpu/cycle efficient: probably if you build strings by hand. Most developer/time/clarity efficient: probably SimpleXML.

Comment: That's subjective. Personally, I find SimpleXml a pain to use compared to what DOM gives me.

Comment: Depends, when having to use namespaces, attributes or validation DOM would have my preference indeed. For just plain unchecked tag/value scenarios SimpleXML is in my opinion a lot less verbose,more to-the-point more easily readable, and I'll try some benchmarks, I suspect it's faster. It is however subjective indeed, I'm defending my opinion here, not facts :)

Comment: I admit I'm biased against SimpleXml. To me the Simple in SimpleXml means *lack of functionality*, not *simplicity of use*. I find the quirky namespace support, implicit interface and lack of verbosity particularly annoying. DOM just offers so much more control over the nodes - but I understand that not everyone needs/wants it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Array2XML](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1826-PHP-Store-associative-array-data-on-file-in-XML.html) class.

Comment: Array2XML is usually much (much!) slower and more CPU intensive then SimpleXML or XMLWriter. I do not have experience with the mentioned class, but previous experiences with other code made me very wary of such design-patters.

Comment: @berkes: Agreed i have proposed this because it is easier for the noobs :) Although decision is there with OP which one he chooses. We have now suggested him both ways :)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php