# Has PHP a function to ENCODE a MySQL Table into XML like ...?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, encode

```
<?xml>
<table>
    <row>
        <columnA>ValueA</columnA>
        <columnB>ValueB</columnB>
        <columnC>ValueC</columnC>
        <columnD>ValueD</columnD>
        <columnE>ValueE</columnE>
    </row>
    <row>
        <columnA>ValueA</columnA>
        <columnB>ValueB</columnB>
        <columnC>ValueC</columnC>
        <columnD>ValueD</columnD>
        <columnE>ValueE</columnE>
    </row>
...
</table>
```

Comment: you can likely adapt the [code shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207599/multidimensional-array-iteration/2207739#2207739)

Answer (score 2):

Some quick Googling reveals this as your best option: http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dom.html

Answer (score 0):

You could either use...

```
htmlentities($table, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Or you could use CDATA...

```
<![CDATA[
<table>
    <row>
        <columnA>ValueA</columnA>
        <columnB>ValueB</columnB>
        <columnC>ValueC</columnC>
        <columnD>ValueD</columnD>
        <columnE>ValueE</columnE>
    </row>
    <row>
        <columnA>ValueA</columnA>
        <columnB>ValueB</columnB>
        <columnC>ValueC</columnC>
        <columnD>ValueD</columnD>
        <columnE>ValueE</columnE>
    </row>
...
</table>
]]>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a function like json_encode that converts an array to JSON format, but in this case to XML

Comment: There isn't a built-in function for that, but there custom functions available... like this one... http://snipplr.com/view/3491/convert-php-array-to-xml-or-simple-xml-object-if-you-wish/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using MDB2-Schema PEAR class to store SQL table structure in XML files.
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2-schema.dump.php