# convert array into .txt file

Tags: php, arrays, file, format, text-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert array into csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933668/convert-array-into-csv)

Hi,

How to convert array into .txt file?

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [OrderList_RetrieveByContactResult] => Array
        (
            [OrderDetails] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [entityId] => 156456
                            [orderId] => 110631
                            [orderName] => testing2
                            [statusTypeId] => 15656
                            [countryCode] => AU
                            [orderType] => 2
                            [invoiceNumber] => 1001
                            [invoiceDate] => 2010-10-19T00:00:00
                            [userID_AssignedTo] => 245454
                            [shippingAmount] => 8.95
                            [shippingTaxRate] => 0
                            [shippingAttention] => tttesst
                            [shippingInstructions] => this a test
                            [shippingOptionId] => 50161
                            [discountCodeId] => 0
                            [discountRate] => 0
                            [totalOrderAmount] => 143.8
                            [directDebitTypeId] => 0
                            [directDebitDays] => 0
                            [isRecur] => 
                            [nextInvoiceDate] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00
                            [endRecurDate] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00
                            [cycleTypeID] => 1
                            [createDate] => 2010-10-19T05:40:00
                            [lastUpdateDate] => 2010-10-19T05:40:00
                            [deleted] => 
                            [products] => Array
                                (
                                    [Product] => Array
                                        (
                                            [productId] => 455
                                            [productCode] => 
                                            [productDescription] => testtest
                                            [units] => 3
                                            [unitPrice] => 44.95
                                            [unitTaxRate] => 0
                                            [totalProductPrice] => 134.85
                                            [productName] => Skin Support Tablets
                                        )
                                )

                            [addresses] => Array
                                (
                                    [Address] => Array
                                        (
                                            [addressTypeID] => 8
                                            [addressLine1] => Cebu
                                            [city] => City
                                            [zipcode] => 6000
                                            [state] => cebu
                                            [countryCode] => PH
                                        )
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [entityId] => 315456
                            [orderId] => 321321
                            [orderName] => testing
                            [statusTypeId] => 3213
                            [countryCode] => AU
                            [orderType] => 2
                            [invoiceNumber] => 1002
                            [invoiceDate] => 2010-10-19T00:00:00
                            [userID_AssignedTo] => 11711
                            [shippingAmount] => 8.95
                            [shippingTaxRate] => 0
                            [shippingAttention] => 
                            [shippingInstructions] => 
                            [shippingOptionId] => 50161
                            [discountCodeId] => 0
                            [discountRate] => 0
                            [totalOrderAmount] => 408.45
                            [directDebitTypeId] => 0
                            [directDebitDays] => 0
                            [isRecur] => 
                            [nextInvoiceDate] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00
                            [endRecurDate] => 0001-01-01T00:00:00
                            [cycleTypeID] => 1
                            [createDate] => 2010-10-08T18:40:00
                            [lastUpdateDate] => 2010-10-19T18:36:00
                            [deleted] => 
                            [products] => Array
                                (
                                    [Product] => Array
                                        (
                                            [productId] => 11564
                                            [productCode] => 
                                            [productDescription] => 
                                            [units] => 10
                                            [unitPrice] => 39.95
                                            [unitTaxRate] => 0
                                            [totalProductPrice] => 399.5
                                            [productName] => Acne Clearing Gel
                                        )

                                )

                            [addresses] => Array
                                (
                                    [Address] => Array
                                        (
                                            [addressTypeID] => 8
                                            [addressLine1] => Cebu City
                                            [city] => Cebu
                                            [zipcode] => 6000
                                            [state] => 
                                            [countryCode] => PH
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Your question is meaningless. .txt files have no structure.

Comment: Can you show your .txt output?

Comment: `file_puts_contents('file.txt', print_r($array, true));`

Comment: Isn't what you display in your question a text file?

Comment: I want to output into .txt file but the format inside the file looks like a csv or excel format. is that possible?

Comment: @rayss: Not with a structure that complex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want it to be parseable, you can use

- `var_export` — Outputs or returns a parsable string representation of a variable

**Example**

```
file_put_contents('array.txt', var_export($array, TRUE));
```

---

If you want it to look like in your question, you pass `TRUE` as the second param to `print_r`:

```
file_put_contents('array.txt', print_r($array, TRUE));
```

---

**EDIT** you mentioned in the comments that you want the array to be transformed to a CSV file. This is more difficult. Your array is nested, while a CSV file is basically a single dim array, e.g.

```
array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2', ... , 'kn' => 'vn');
```

would be equivalent to a CSV file where the first rows is the array keys and the second row the values.

```
k1; k2; ...; kn
v1; v2; ...; vn
```

The single dims arrays are usually inside another array, so you have a collection like this:

```
array(
   array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2', ... , 'kn' => 'vn'),
   array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2', ... , 'kn' => 'vn')
);
```

Here, you'd have to get the keys first and then fetch only the values from the array for the subsequent lines, e.g.

```
k1; k2; ...; kn
v1; v2; ...; vn
v1; v2; ...; vn
```

The problem is, your array is nested even deeper. Where would you put the *address* array? The only feasible approach would be to go over the array and fetch only those keys and values that contain a scalar type and linearize any nested arrays, e.g.

```
array(
   array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2', ... , 'kn' => array( 'skn' => 'svn' ) ),
   array('k1' => 'v1', 'k2' => 'v2', ... , 'kn' => array( 'skn' => 'svn' ) ),
);
```

has to be turned into

```
k1; k2; ...; skn
v1; v2; ...; svn
v1; v2; ...; svn
```

In case this isnt clear, here is an illustration what goes where:

[image: Flattening a Multidimensional Array for use in a CSV file]

Luckily, this can be achieved with Iterators:

```
$orderDetails = $array['OrderList_RetrieveByContactResult']['OrderDetails'];
foreach( $orderDetails as $key => $details ) {

    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator($details));

    if($key === 0) {
        $keys = array();
        foreach($iterator as $k => $v) {
            $keys[] = $k;
        }
        echo implode(';', $keys);
    }

    $values = array();
    foreach($iterator as $val) {
        $values[] = $val;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL, implode(';', $values);
}
```

The above code should output the described format. See http://www.ideone.com/I70dD for an example.

To write this to a file, you can either assemble this to a string variable and then `file_put_contents` it all at once or you use a filepointer and write it line by line. If you dont `implode` it but iterate over the `$flattened` array, you can also use `fputcsv`.

Comment: Surely you don't want to pass true as the second argument in var_export as this exports it to a vairable rather than outputting the contents?

Comment: @Alex I want to pass it to `file_put_contents` so it can be written to a file. For that, I have to use `TRUE`.

Comment: thank you for your post it helps me a lot but theres a little problem with your code. It appears the the [countryCode] => AU does not appear instead it will replace the [countryCode] => PH from the array of product. Heres what i get: 
156456;110631;testing2;15656;PH;2;.... etc
315456;321321;testing;3213;PH;2.... etc

Comment: @rayss that's because `iterator_to_array` assembles the array it returns in memory first and keys from a nested level will overwrite higher level keys of the same name. I have updated the code. Now it shouldnt do that anymore. If you want more control over the Iteration, you might also want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207599/multidimensional-array-iteration/2207739#2207739

Comment: thank you so much its really works. thanks for the help. I learned a lot from you :)

Answer (score 9):

If you want to save a variable in a text file, you could use the [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) / [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions for that:

```
$data = array(1, 2, 3, '');
$toBeSaved = serialize($data);
file_put_contents('somefile.txt', $toBeSaved);
```

And restore it...

```
$toBeRestored = file_get_contents('somefile.txt');
$data = unserialize($toBeRestored);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want is [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) ?

Comment: Not with a structure that complex.

Comment: So what structure do you want ?