# Transform a multidimensional array to XML and then use a recursive XSLT function

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have a function in PHP that retrieves all the directories and files from a given path. This returns me an array like:

```
array(
    "dirname1" => array(
        "dirname2" => array(
            "dirname3" => array(
                "0" => "file1",
                "1" => "file2",
                "2" => "file3"
            ),
            "0" => "file4",
            "1" => "file5",
            "2" => "file6",
            "dirname4" => array(
                "0" => "file7",
                "1" => "file8"
            )
        ),
        "0" => "file9",
        "1" => "file10"
    ),
    "0" => "file11",
    "1" => "file12",
    "2" => "file13"
);
```

What I finally need is a multidimensional (don't know if is the exactly word) list with `<ul />` and `<li />` generated with XSLT 1.0 from a XML file, like:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dirname">
        dirname1
        <ul>
            <li class="dirname">
                Dirname2
                <ul>
                    <li class="dirname">
                        Dirname3
                        <ul>
                            <li>file1</li>
                            <li>file2</li>
                            <li>file3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>file4</li>
                    <li>file5</li>
                    <li>file6</li>
                    <li class="dirname">
                        dirname4
                        <ul>
                            <li>file7</li>
                            <li>file8</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>file9</li>
            <li>file10</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>file11</li>
    <li>file12</li>
    <li>file13</li>
</ul>
```

And finally, inside every `<li />` I need the path in a `<a />`, like:

```
<li class="dirname"><a href="/dirname1">dirname1</a></li>

<li><a href="/dirname1/dirname2/dirname3/file1">file1</a></li>

<li><a href="/dirname1/file9">file9</a></li>
```

Actually I don't have the XML that I need to convert because I don't know what can be a nice structure for then convert it to XSLT 1.0. I have the paths inside the `<a />`. I can do it with PHP if necessary and I can detect in PHP when it is a directory or when not and we can also add something on the XML to detect the `class="dirname"`.

I hope I've given sufficient information to understand me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multidimensional array iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207599/multidimensional-array-iteration)

Comment: @Gordon: I also need a recursive function in XSLT, is not what they ask on your link. Thank you anyway. :)

Comment: @Gordon: sorry, English is not my main language. The ul/li output list needs to be generated from an XML file. I added this: *What I finally need is a multidimensional (don't know if is the exactly word) list with <ul /> and <li /> **generated with XSLT 1.0 from a XML file***

Comment: @udexter why do you have to do it with an XSLT? Why cant you just create the html output from the multidimensional php array?

Comment: @udexter: Why not swap multidimensional with recursive in your title? It's probably better to understand? It's just an idea?

Comment: @Gordon: because the (private) framework/MVC where I'm developing are using XML for the data output and XSLT for rendering the view. :(

Comment: @udexter: Very smart I wanted to do same a long time ago. It's not that difficult. Did you checked http://www.w3schools.com/xsl?

Comment: @epitaph: Is where i learned :P. I've almost the website done, with the ability to separate footer, headers, sidebars... or like taking, for a multilingual site, the text from a XML lang file. It's very clean, because we've all the data on a XML file and it's easy for human read... but there are things like this that are difficult for a non-advance XML/XSLT programmer. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tunneling parameter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:param name="pPath"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
                <xsl:with-param name="pPath" select="$pPath"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li[@class='dirname']">
        <xsl:param name="pPath"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity">
            <xsl:with-param name="pPath"
             select="concat($pPath,'/',normalize-space(text()[1]))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:param name="pPath"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="text">
            <xsl:with-param name="pPath"
             select="concat($pPath,'/',normalize-space())"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="li[@class='dirname']/text()" name="text">
        <xsl:param name="pPath"/>
        <a href="{$pPath}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dirname">
        <a href="/dirname1">
            dirname1
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li class="dirname">
                <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2">
                    Dirname2
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="dirname">
                        <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/Dirname3">
                            Dirname3
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/Dirname3/file1"
                                >file1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/Dirname3/file2"
                                >file2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/Dirname3/file3"
                                >file3</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/file4">file4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/file5">file5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/file6">file6</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dirname">
                        <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/dirname4">
                            dirname4
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/dirname4/file7"
                                >file7</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/dirname1/Dirname2/dirname4/file8"
                                >file8</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/dirname1/file9">file9</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/dirname1/file10">file10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/file11">file11</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/file12">file12</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/file13">file13</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Alejandro: thank you for your XSLT. What is your XML input like? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've tried with this input, but I don't get the same output: http://pastebin.com/Jj5gB2Nk

Comment: @udexter: I'm using the input you post. The new one you link it hasn't any @class equal to `"dirname"`.

Comment: @Alejandro: Ah! That was the final needed output, what I need in HTML. I didn't know what was a nice structure to process it with XML to obtain that finally HTML. Do you suggest a better XML?

Comment: @udexter: Any schema will work as long as it has all the information... We all are using the one you post. If that is not the proper one, please update.

Comment: It's right with that. I was putting the final HTML output because i didn't know any better way but if this works is perfect. So accept and +1 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**PHP part**

```
function ulRenderer($dirs, $path = array()) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($dirs as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            printf(
                '<li class="dirname"><a href="%s">%s</a>',
                implode('/', $path),
                $key
            );

            ulRenderer($value, array_merge(
                $path, array($key)
            ));
            echo '</li>';
        }
        else {
            printf(
                '<li><a href="%s/%s">%s</a></li>',
                implode('/', $path),
                $value, $value
            );
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

$dirs = array(
    "dirname1" => array(
        "dirname2" => array(
            "dirname3" => array(
                "0" => "file1",
                "1" => "file2",
                "2" => "file3"
            ),
            "0" => "file4",
            "1" => "file5",
            "2" => "file6",
            "dirname4" => array(
                "0" => "file7",
                "1" => "file8"
            )
        ),
        "0" => "file9",
        "1" => "file10"
    ),
    "0" => "file11",
    "1" => "file12",
    "2" => "file13"
);


ulRenderer($dirs);
```

**XML/XSL part**

**dirs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<root>
    <dir name="dirname1">
        <dir name="dirname2">
            <dir name="dirname3">
                <file>file1</file>
                <file>file2</file>
                <file>file3</file>
            </dir>

            <dir name="dirname4">
                <file>file4</file>
                <file>file5</file>
            </dir>

            <file>file6</file>
            <file>file7</file>
            <file>file8</file>
        </dir>

        <file>file11</file>
        <file>file12</file>
        <file>file13</file>
    </dir>
</root>
```

**dirs.xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="dir">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:call-template name="path" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                </a>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <li>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:call-template name="path" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="path">
        <xsl:if test="parent::dir">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::dir">
                <xsl:sort select="position()" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name() = 'dir'">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and php again**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('dirs.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('dirs.xslt', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($xsl);

echo $xslt->transformToXML($dom);
```

Comment: Thank you! It will be helpful when generating the XML structure. Now see if someone can help me with the XSLT part!