# How to get the current recursion level in a PHP function

Tags: php, recursion

How can I get the current recursion level in a PHP function?

I mean, is there any "magical" (or eventually normal) function like the following?

```
function doSomething($things) {
    if (is_array($things)) {
        foreach ($things as $thing) {
            doSomething($thing);
        }
    } else {
        // This is what I want:
        echo current_recursion_level();
    }
}
```

I know I can use another function argument (`$level` in this example):

```
function doSomething($things, $level = 0) {
    if (is_array($things)) {
        foreach ($things as $thing) {
            $level++;
            doSomething($thing, $level);
        }
    } else {
        echo $level;
    }
}
```

But I want to know if there is a built-in function (or trick) to do that. Maybe something with `debug_backtrace()`, but it does not seem to be a simple or quick solution.

I did not found this information. Maybe it simply does not exists...

Comment: Use a static variable.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900123/recursive-tree-traversal-how-to-keep-track-of-the-recursion-level?rq=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are just looking to avoid hitting PHP's 100 level recursion limit then

```
count(debug_backtrace());
```

should be sufficient.  Otherwise you've no choice to pass a depth argument, though the precrement operator makes it somewhat cleaner as seen in the example below.

```
function recursable ( $depth = 0 ) {
  if ($depth > 3) {
    debug_print_backtrace();
    return true;
  } else {
    return recursable( ++$depth );
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI the recursion limit isn't from PHP but comes from Xdebug extension https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level

Comment: Can you qualify the 100 level recursion limit in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to count it yourself. The only alternative would be something like [Xdebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdebug) which profiles your complete software. But this is highly inefficient.

```
<?php
    function my_recursive_fn($param) {
        static $counter = 0;
        if (is_array($param)) {
            ++$counter;
            foreach ($param as $k => $v) {

            }
        }
        else {
            echo $counter;
            --$counter;

            // If we're returning (only PHP 5.5+)
            try {
                return $counter;
            }
            finally {
                --$counter;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

This allows you to count without a second public parameter.

Comment: Using `static` is okay, but you're counting the total number of array elements instead of the recursion level. To do the latter, just increment the variable at the start of the function and decrease it before returning.

Comment: Don't you need to decrement `$counter` before returning?

Comment: Of course, corrected it to really count the recursion. The OP has the incrementing in the loop.

Comment: Why decrement? The function was actually called. Depends highly on the use-case.

Comment: Because when you return, you're no longer at the higher recursion level. And the next time you start the recursion from the beginning, recursion level should start at 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can inspect the call stack. I think you can do the same in PHP:

[debug-backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) may be the one you are looking for.

Since PHP does not optimize recursion with tail calls this should tell you the depth of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function select($modules, $level = 0)
{
    $return_html = '';
    $level_html = '';
    $new_level = 0;

    foreach($modules as $module)
    {
        $repeat = str_repeat('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $level);

        if(!empty($module['children']))
        {
            $return_html .= '<option>' . $repeat . ' ' . $module['title'] . '</option>';

            $new_level = $level + 1;

            $return_html .= $this->select($module['children'], $new_level);
        }
        else
        {
            $return_html .= '<option>' . $repeat . ' ' . $module['title'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    return $return_html;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63901677/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -1):

```
function doSomething($things) {
    static $level = 0;
    if (is_array($things)) {
        foreach ($things as $thing) {
            $level++;
            doSomething($thing);
        }
    }
    else {
        // This is what I want:
        echo $level
    }
}
```

Comment: Imho you need to decrement $level after the call to your function.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19926118/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).