# Nested arrays with undefinded lenght: Get most nested array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops, multidimensional-array

I am doing a request to an API and for each request I get an array with the BrowseNodes back. Inside this array I get this result:

```
array:1 [
  "BrowseNode" => array:3 [
    "BrowseNodeId" => "2502033031"
    "Name" => "OBD-II Diagnosewerkzeuge"
    "Ancestors" => array:1 [
      "BrowseNode" => array:3 [
        "BrowseNodeId" => "5142250031"
        "Name" => "Motorwerkzeuge & Zubehör"
        "Ancestors" => array:1 [
          "BrowseNode" => array:3 [
            "BrowseNodeId" => "2502064031"
            "Name" => "Werkzeuge"
            "Ancestors" => array:1 [
              "BrowseNode" => array:4 [
                "BrowseNodeId" => "79899031"
                "Name" => "Kategorien"
                "IsCategoryRoot" => "1"
                "Ancestors" => array:1 [
                  "BrowseNode" => array:2 [
                    "BrowseNodeId" => "78191031"
                    "Name" => "Auto & Motorrad"
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

If this would be a fixed array which always had this length it would be easy for me to get the last BrowseNode Array and the value with the key "Name". In this case it would be the this one `"Name" => "Auto & Motorrad"`.

### However, because a category can have one or more nested arrays, it is not static...

**That means I have to find a solution to always get the most nested array and from this one the name to get the category.** Because it is dynamic data, I don't know how to solve that. I just know I always have to get the `BrowseNode` and then inside the `BrowseNode` array.  I have to get the `Ancestors` and inside this `Ancestors` again. I have to get the `BrowseNode` array until I arrived at the last `BrowseNode` array and the get the name.

So, I have to iterate through my array until the `BrowseNode` array doesn't have an `Ancestors` array anymore and the get the name of this `BrowseNode` array.

Do you guys have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Your question would be clearer (better understood about task requirements) if you included sample data that has a fork in it.  Then you could explain better about the "depth" factor.

Comment: @Jan Did my post answer you or I miss-understood the question?

Comment: Yeah, it did. Sorry, forgot to upvote it! :) @DavidWinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use recursion to achieve that.

On each object, search for `Ancestors`, if not found return the name, else do so again on the Ancestors.

Consider the following code:

```
$arr = array("BrowseNode" => array("BrowseNodeId" => "1", "Ancestors" => array("BrowseNode" => array("BrowseNodeId" => "2", "Ancestors" => array("BrowseNode" => array("BrowseNodeId" => "3"))))));

function getLastName($elem) {
    $elem = $elem["BrowseNode"];
    if (!array_key_exists("Ancestors", $elem))
         return $elem['BrowseNodeId'];
    else return getLastName($elem["Ancestors"]);
}

echo getLastName($arr);
```

Notice that this code return `id` instead of your `Name` - small modification I leave to you...

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more "correct" way of doing this but since I'm writing this on my phone on a plane, you'll have to forgive my not being able to proof check my answer. But you could do a recursive function, like...

```
function recurseArray($browseNode) 
{
    if(isset($browseNode["Ancestors"])) {
        recurseArray($browseNode["Ancestors"]["browseNode"])
    } else {
        // Do whatever you want with the last iteration
    }
}
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Is there any important diff between this and my answer?

Comment: No, it's practically the same, you beat me to it. Points should go to Sir David Winder

Comment: @DavidWinder I don't think either of your answers are checking for the "deepest" data.  Read the fineprint in the question.

Comment: @mickmackusa can you enlighten me please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925970/how-to-get-current-recursion-level-in-a-php-function